# Push List<string> into dictionary value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to push List of type string into value dictionary in js script.
Js dictionary should contain key DateTime, and List as a value.

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, List<string>> item in Model.AssignedAttractions)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dictionary = [];

        $(function () {
            dictionary.push({
                key: @item.Key.ToShortDateString(),
                value: @item.Value.ToArray(),
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Presented solution `value: @item.Value.ToArray()`is not working.

Comment: try if this works `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(item.Value))`

Comment: Should it work in Razor View? It shows me Json doesn't contain definition Serialize

Comment: add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` to the top of your view

Comment: No change after added import. Should Json be imported from System.Web.Helpers?

Comment: sorry try with `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value))`

Comment: Displaying keys should look like this: console.log(Object.keys(dictionary));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154068/discussion-between-maciejka-and-adiga).

Comment: I don't understand. Is it working?

Comment: I have put elements into dictionary but I want to check added keys and values, so this command -> console.log(Object.keys(dictionary)); should display added elements(keys in this case) in my browser?

Comment: @adiga your proposal is working fine. I asked addtional question, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: If there are 2 items in `dictionary`, `Object.keys(dictionary)` returns ["0", "1"]. I think what you want is `Object.keys(dictionary[0])` . This will return `["key", "value"]`. (Make sure array is not empty before indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` to your `View`. And then,

```
dictionary.push({
    key: @item.Key.ToShortDateString(),
    value: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value)),
});
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` converts your C# object to a JSON string

You could also avoid the loop like this:

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AssignedAttractions.Select(a => new { key = a.Key.ToShortDateString(), value = a.Value })));
```